# Как подставлять строку к каждому слову JavaScript

Tags: javascript, перебор

Искал данный вопрос в интернете, но конкретно ничего не нашел. В общем я хочу чтобы не писать каждый раз

```
bot2.setControlState('forward', true)
bot3.setControlState('forward', true)
bot4.setControlState('forward', true)
И так далее ...
```

Я хочу все сделать лаконичнее, но так как я новичок не получается. У меня в голове вот такая картинка (смотреть ниже) но никак не могу придти к решению.

```
var bots = [bot , bot2 , bot3 , bot4 , bot5 , bot6 , bot7]
for (key in bot) {
    и тут каждое слово(bot,bot1 ..) подставляется к фразе setControlState('forward', true)
```

Как это все сделать, надеюсь получится!

Comment: `for (const bot of bots) bot.setControlState('forward', true);` или `bots.forEach(bot => bot.setControlState('forward', true));`. А вообще, вместо напихивания 7 переменных в промежуточный массив, лучше бы изначально работать с массивом из семи (или сколько нужно) элементов...

Comment: В обоих случаях пишет вот это bot.setControlState('forward', true);
        ^

TypeError: bot.setControlState is not a function

Comment: _«подставлять строку»_ - тут не строка подставляется, а имя переменной. Это совсем разные вещи. JS позволяет найти свойство в объекте по строке имени (свойства), но нельзя получить переменную по ее имени (без использования опасных практик типа eval).

Comment: Да, извиняюсь что написал "подставлять строку", на самом деле это не проблема просто хотелось бы лаконичнее, если нельзя то так уж и быть

Comment: _«пишет вот это ... setControlState is not a function»_ - это говорит о том что значение свойства `setControlState`, которое пытаешься вызывать как функцию - по факту не является функцией. Вероятнее всего, такое свойство у перебираемых объектов есть, но оно имеет какой-то другой тип (по-моему, если бы свойства не было вовсе, то ошибка была бы другой... но вообще хз, такой вариант тоже возможен).

Comment: @yar85 Отнюдь - `({}).setControlState();` - `TypeError: {}.setControlState is not a function`